# Checking CAN Bus on oscilloscope

Tags: arduino, oscilloscope, can

I'm using "Arduino MCP2515 CAN bus Module TJA1050 receiver" for sending and receiving frames. I connect the bus of 2 modules and send frame from one and receive from the other. I got the correct frame on the serial monitor of Arduino but when I check the bus signal on the oscilloscope but I can't see the frame. This is the picture of my setup:[image] and here is the answer I got:[image] this is the link of send and receive code that I used:http://henrysbench.capnfatz.com/henrys-bench/arduino-projects-tips-and-more/arduino-can-bus-module-1st-network-tutorial/
Can someone please help me How can I see the frame?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: " but I can't see the frame." Can you get any more unspecific?

Comment: This is going to rely primarily on your probing method, your scope's specs, and the settings for both the scope and Arduino. We can't guess any of those. Please post pic or at least an adequate description of what you're doing.

Comment: Actually I don't know what should I get on the bus of CAN transceiver. I think if I send the ID and data to CAN, I can see the frame on the bus. Is it wrong?@PlasmaHH

Comment: *"Can't see the frame"* is a useless description.  Does that mean you are seeing the bits, but don't know how to interpret them into frames?  Can't make out individual bits? All you see is flat line?  We have no idea how exactly you connected the scope, how you set it up, and how much you know about interpreting the result.  This really should have been obvious.

Comment: Did you calibrate two 10:1 probes on a square wave and use A-B with short grounds to get a flat line then measure differential signal? Or what? Then set a smart trigger.

Comment: This is effectively a duplicate of [your previous question from yesterday](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/397558) - except there you gave *more* details. Duplicating questions on this site is not allowed, there is even a specific closure reason for this. As you have received an answer on *this* question, and not on yesterday's question, I'm going to start the closure process on yesterday's question as a duplicate of this one. Please don't duplicate questions here again. If you don't get a reply to a question, [do this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/no-one-answers). Thanks

Comment: I edit my question and enter the images. Please notice it. I don't know what are the signals that I got. There isn't any relation between the frame I send and the signals that apear on the bus.@Olin Lathrop  @Phil C

Comment: It's still unclear to me what you intend to mean by frame, or specifically what you expect to see on the scope. The TDS2024B does not have CAN bus (or any) protocol decoding. All you'll get is the raw bitstream. You can zoom out (select a longer time base on horizontal) and manually decode each bit visually, but you'll never see decoded text with that scope.

Comment: @SamGibson: That question has been deleted now (*"404 ... This question was voluntarily removed by its author."*). Probably due to downvotes, but I can't see that (you can!).

Comment: One can export the data from the TDS2024B (e.g. with the API or manually via a USB stick), somehow convert it (say, by a series of Perl scripts) to the format expected by the free [Sigrok](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigrok) (say, for CSV import) and use the (now fixed) CAN protocol decoder. I have done it... A blog post is coming, but I can not promise when.

Comment: @Peter - Hi, Thanks for the update and +1 for your decode suggestion. I just checked and as you say, the OP deleted that earlier question (with 1 downvote) on Sept 25. It contained source code but no hardware info, whereas *this* question contains hardware info but (originally) no code. The code from that earlier question was (we now know due to an update in *this* question) a copy of the "transmit node" code from [this web page](http://henrysbench.capnfatz.com/henrys-bench/arduino-projects-tips-and-more/arduino-can-bus-module-1st-network-tutorial/) added to *this* question as a later update.

Answer (score 3):

To measure CAN bus on an oscilloscope, connect it as follows:

- CH1 to Can H
- CH2 to Can L
- GND to Can GND

Use the MATH channel in subtract mode to view the frames.
Trigger on MATH, or if that is unavailable, one of the channels rising edge with a hold-off time similar to the frame length.

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I did it but when I change the ID or data, the result on oscilloscope isn't change. Would you please help me?@Jeroen3

Comment: Measuring the bus differentially is completely overkill. It should be sufficient just to watch CAN H. As for what a certain scope needs in order to decode raw CAN with a signal decoder feature, that's another story entirely.

Comment: An alternative trigger scheme is a negative pulse longer than 5.5 bit times (26 µsec for 250 kbit/s). Similary, a positive pulse longer than 5.5 bit times for triggering on CAN error frames.